# Java Frame and Graphics

Tags: graphics, jframe, java, swing

Добрый день.

У меня вопрос следующего характера. Есть класс Sd и класс Main. Sd - содержит в себе создание фрейма, а Main рисует фигурки. Как сделать так, чтобы из класса Main, фигурки рисовала на класс Sd, т.е. фрейм.

Помогите пожалуйста, я еще только изучаю Java :)

Класс Main:

```
package org.jazzteam.teamtask;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Applet {
   int width, height;

   public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        super.paint(g);
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2d.setColor( Color.red );
       g2d.fillRect( 10, 20, 10, 15 );
       g2d.setColor( Color.pink );
       g2d.fillRect( 30, 40, 20, 20 );
       g2d.setColor( Color.red );
       g2d.fillRect( 10, 20, 10, 15 );
       g2d.setColor( Color.green );
       g2d.fillRect( 40,75, 30, 30 );
       g2d.setColor( Color.red );
       g2d.fillRect( 10, 20, 10, 15 );
       g2d.setColor( Color.blue );
       g2d.fillRect( 80, 60, 40, 20 );

   }
}

package org.jazzteam.teamtask;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Sd extends JFrame {

    public static final Font FONT = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11);

    public static void createGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Игровое Поле");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent event) {

            }

            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent event) {

            }

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                Object[] options = { "Да", "Нет!" };
                int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(event.getWindow(),
                        "Закрыть окно?", "Подтверждение",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
                if (n == 0) {
                    event.getWindow().setVisible(false);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }

            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent event) {

            }

            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent event) {

            }

            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent event) {

            }

            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent event) {

            }

        });

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UIManager.put("Button.font", FONT);
                UIManager.put("Label.font", FONT);
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Я пробовал создавать объект на класс Main:

```
private Main main;
```

и в методе run() вызывать метод из класса Main:

```
Sd object = new Sd();
```

object.main.paint(); - paint это метод из класса Main, оно просит передать параметры, в моем случае если я пишу null, то ничего не ресует, если пишу g ( имя перемменой), выдает ошибку. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не уверен что правильно понял что вам нужно но так рисует:

```
package org.jazzteam.teamtask ;

import java.applet.Applet ;
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter ;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent ;
import javax.swing.JDialog ;
import javax.swing.JFrame ;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane ;
import javax.swing.UIManager ;

public class Sd extends JFrame
{
    private class MainApplet extends Applet
    {
        @Override
        public void paint ( final Graphics g )
        {
            super.paint ( g ) ;
            final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g ;
            g2d.setColor ( Color.red ) ;
            g2d.fillRect ( 10, 20, 10, 15 ) ;
            g2d.setColor ( Color.pink ) ;
            g2d.fillRect ( 30, 40, 20, 20 ) ;
            g2d.setColor ( Color.red ) ;
            g2d.fillRect ( 10, 20, 10, 15 ) ;
            g2d.setColor ( Color.green ) ;
            g2d.fillRect ( 40, 75, 30, 30 ) ;
            g2d.setColor ( Color.red ) ;
            g2d.fillRect ( 10, 20, 10, 15 ) ;
            g2d.setColor ( Color.blue ) ;
            g2d.fillRect ( 80, 60, 40, 20 ) ;

        }
    }

    public static final Font FONT = new Font ( "Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11 ) ;

    public Sd ()
    {
        super ( "Игровое Поле" ) ;
        setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE ) ;

        addWindowListener ( new WindowAdapter ()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing ( final WindowEvent event )
            {
                final Object[] options = { "Да", "Нет!" } ;
                final int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog ( event.getWindow (), "Закрыть окно?", "Подтверждение",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0] ) ;
                if ( n == 0 )
                {
                    event.getWindow ().setVisible ( false ) ;
                    System.exit ( 0 ) ;
                }
            }
        } ) ;

        add ( new MainApplet () ) ;
        setPreferredSize ( new Dimension ( 700, 500 ) ) ;
        pack () ;
        setLocationRelativeTo ( null ) ;
    }

    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                UIManager.put ( "Button.font", FONT ) ;
                UIManager.put ( "Label.font", FONT ) ;
                JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated ( true ) ;
                JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated ( true ) ;
                new Sd ().setVisible ( true ) ;
            }
        } ) ;
    }
}
```